# Comprobar solapamiento en intervalos de horas

Tags: vb.net, comparaciones

Actualmente tengo la necesidad de comparar si un tramo en horas se solapa con otro tramo de horas, la verdad es que me estoy haciendo un lio y no acabo de ver que es lo que no esta bien, os adjunto lo que tengo hecho a ver si veis el error:

1. Los tramos son HoraIni-HoraFin y tramoDesde-tramoHasta
2. son numeros enteros
3. un tramo por ejemplo de 1 a 3 y el otro de 3 a 6 no se consideran
   solapados

```
If ((tramoDesde < HoraIni And HoraIni > tramoHasta) Or (tramoDesde < HoraFin And tramoHasta > HoraFin) Or (tramoDesde >= HoraIni And tramoHasta <= HoraFin)) Then
    Solapados = True
End If
```

imagino que al final sera un detalle o algo en la comparacion

Comment: Solo necesitas saber si se solapan? Usas enteros en lugar de DateTime?

Comment: hola @Pikoh , son enteros, pero definen un intervalo, por ejemplo 2-4 y 3-5 se solaparian, sin embargo 1-3 y 3-7 no o 1-5 y 2-4 si o 3-6 y 1-8 tambien

Answer (score 0):

Hay una libreria en CodeProject que se encarga de revisar esto y otras cosas

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/168662/time-period-library-for-net

No la he utilizado pero tiene buena referencia

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514069/3596441

Answer (score 0):

Hay una formula muy sencilla para comprobar si dos periodos se solapan:

```
int HoraIni = 3;
int HoraFin = 6;
int tramoDesde = 1;
int tramoHasta = 8;
bool solape = HoraIni < tramoHasta && tramoDesde < HoraFin;
```

**Edit**

Perdón,era VB.NET:

```
Dim HoraIni As Integer = 3
Dim HoraFin As Integer = 6
Dim tramoDesde As Integer = 1
Dim tramoHasta As Integer = 8
Dim solape As Boolean = HoraIni < tramoHasta AndAlso tramoDesde < HoraFin
```